# CISCO Configuration. DHCP & VLAN configured. But can't ping other VLAN clients

Tags: cisco, dhcp, command-line-interface, vlan

I have created a network testing lab with CISCO Packet Tracer. I have performed the following to get a DHCP and VLAN (with Trucking) working:

1. Configured Router interfaces (g0/0 + g0/0.10-0.50)
2. Configured DHCP settings on Router
3. Enabled Trunk on Router
4. Configured VLAN on Switch
5. Enabled Trunk on Switch

Below I post the >show run< for the router and the Switch. Workstations can gain an DHCP IP address, and VLAN segregation is working.

Workstations can ping the router but can't ping other workstations on separate VLAN networks.

Router Configuration

```
shanelab#show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2184 bytes
!
version 15.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname shanelab
!
!
!
enable secret 5 $1$mERr$xqDCepYvK4SAD6V0cxKQ3.
!
!
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.10.1 192.168.10.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.20.1 192.168.20.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.30.1 192.168.30.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.40.1 192.168.40.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.50.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.60.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.50.1 192.168.50.10
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.60.1 192.168.60.10
!
ip dhcp pool ITC
 network 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.165.10.1
ip dhcp pool Manuf
 network 192.168.20.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.20.1
ip dhcp pool billing
 network 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.30.1
ip dhcp pool sales
 network 192.168.40.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.40.1
ip dhcp pool HR
 network 192.168.50.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.50.1
ip dhcp pool Management
 network 192.168.60.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 192.168.60.1
!
!
!
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1941/K9 sn FTX1524KDLE-
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.40
 encapsulation dot1Q 40
 ip address 192.168.40.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.50
 encapsulation dot1Q 50
 ip address 192.168.50.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.60
 encapsulation dot1Q 60
 ip address 192.168.60.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless

shanelab#
shanelab#
```

Switch Configuration

```
Switch#show run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1385 bytes
!
version 15.0
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 20
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport access vlan 30
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/4
 switchport access vlan 40
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/5
 switchport access vlan 50
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/6
 switchport access vlan 60
!
interface FastEthernet0/7
!
interface FastEthernet0/8
!
interface FastEthernet0/9
!
interface FastEthernet0/10
!
interface FastEthernet0/11
!
interface FastEthernet0/12
!
interface FastEthernet0/13
!
interface FastEthernet0/14
!
interface FastEthernet0/15
!
interface FastEthernet0/16
!
interface FastEthernet0/17
!
interface FastEthernet0/18
!
interface FastEthernet0/19
!
interface FastEthernet0/20
!
interface FastEthernet0/21
!
interface FastEthernet0/22
!
interface FastEthernet0/23
!
interface FastEthernet0/24
 switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
!
end


Switch#
```

Comment: This looks like a homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your configurations. You can use simulation mode when ping to determine what happened with ICMP packets.

Comment: Thanks, by using the simulation mode I was able to work out that there was a configuration error with the switch. (I had the Switch IP VLAN1 IP address, assigned to a different network then the router)